# Get DAY from Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need select day from @ReportDay

```
DECLARE @ReportDay DATETIME = '2017-10-02 12:00:03.140' 
DECLARE @currentReportDay DATETIME = DATEPART(day, @ReportDay )
```

But in result I've '1900-01-03 00:00:00.000'. How it can be fix?

Comment: If you want an integer, change `@currentReportDay DATETIME` to `@currentReportDay int`

Comment: I need DATETIMe

Comment: then define __fixed__ ?

Comment: Please let us know what you would like as a result? Is it "2" as in the second day of October? Or "Monday" as in the day of the week? Or something else?

Comment: The question is unclear, but if you mean you want a datetime of the day (i.e. remove the time), you can do something like DECLARE @currentReportDay DATETIME = CAST(CAST(@ReportDay AS DATE) AS DATETIME)

Comment: Kirill, did any of the below answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ReportDay DATETIME = FORMAT(Now(),'YYYY-MM-DD')
DECLARE @currentReportDay DATETIME = DATEPART(day, @ReportDay)
```

This would give you today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: DATEPART(day, @ReportDay) will actually yield and integer not a DATETIME.  NOW() isn't sql-server function but GETDATE() would be its equivalent.  and FORMAT() would actually convert the DATETIME to a string which then has to be converted back and is basically a SQL implementation of .Net's FORMAT() and its performance is not good but probably fine for assigning a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEPART` gives you back an integer

```
DECLARE @ReportDay DATETIME = '2017-10-02 12:00:03.140' 
DECLARE @currentReportDay INT = DATEPART(day, @ReportDay )
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already raised the ambiguity of your question but to add some explanation and hopefully clear up some confusion.

The reason why you are getting '1900-01-03 00:00:00.000'

is because `DATEPART(day, @ReportDay)` will return an integer for the day of the month, in your case `2`.  When converted to a DATETIME 2 is actually the 3rd date.  `0 is 1/1/1900, 1 is 1/2/1900`.  and so forth.

So if you want the `DATE` itself you can use `CONVERT` or `CAST`.  Some other string manipulation techniques exist and `FORMAT()` is one of them but they are not worth looking at as will have much poorer performance and take additional `CASTS` and `CONVERTS` anyway.  What you want to do is to *DROP* the `TIME` off the `DATETIME`.  Best way of doing that is to `CAST` it to a `DATE` which has no `TIME` component.

```
DECLARE @currentReportDay DATETIME = CAST(CAST(@ReportDay AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
```

Note because the second `CAST` back to `DATETIME` isn't really necessary in this code as it will inherently happen so you could shorten to:

```
DECLARE @currentReportDay DATETIME = CAST(@ReportDay AS DATE)
```

And to round this out.  If you actually want the *DAY of the Month* then simply change from `DATETIME` data type to `INT`.

```
DECLARE @currentReportDay INT = DATEPART(day, @ReportDay )
```